# Call Macro on a specific sheet / Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I want to run a macro on a specific sheet, in my case the sheet is called "Tablet".

If a cell value in "Tabelle1" changes, I want to run this macro in the "Tablet" sheet.

Code in my Tabelle1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
        Call Delete_OptionB1
    End If
End Sub
```

This part works.

Macro Code:

```
Sub Delete_OptionB1()
'
' Delete_OptionB1 Makro
'
     With Worksheets("Tablet")
    .Range("M2:AD2").Select
     Selection.ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

This wont do the job. Any suggestions how I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code using a with block

```
 With Worksheets("Tablet")
.Range("M2:AD2").Select
 Selection.ClearContents
End With
```

You are selecting `.Range("M2:AD2").Select` but then clearing the contents of the selection on whatever sheet may be active when you `Delete_OptionB1`. Change to include a . - `.Selection.ClearContents`.

Even better, get rid or the `With...End With` and `Select` altogether.  A single line will do it all:

```
Sub Delete_OptionB2()
'
' Delete_OptionB1 Makro
'
    Worksheets("Tablet").Range("M2:AD2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: @Mark Just a note: A `.Selection` does not exist in the `Worksheet` object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of …

```
Target.Address = "$C$2"
```

… better use the [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Intersect) to make it work if `Target` is more than one cell (this can happen when you copy/paste a range):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
        Delete_OptionB1 'you don't need the Call statement
    End If
End Sub
```

If `Delete_OptionB1` is not in a public module but in a workbook use eg `Tablet.Delete_OptionB1`

---

Make `Delete_OptionB1` public, and avoid using `.Select` and `Selection.` (also see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba))

```
Public Sub Delete_OptionB1() 'make it public
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tablet").Range("M2:AD2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the `Tabelle1` **worksheet code area**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$C$2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call Delete_OptionB1
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Place this in a **standard module**:

```
Sub Delete_OptionB1()
'
' Delete_OptionB1 Makro
'
     With Worksheets("Tablet")
        .Range("M2:AD2").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Call` is deprecated.